# I cannot get my top navigation social media bar to show

Tags: html, css

```
             <section class="desktop_navigation">
<div class="block explore main with_dropdown">
  <div class="positioner"><img src="images/headers/connect.png">
```

International HQs
        The BluPrint
        Other Regions 
        Sigma Exchange
        ZPhiB International HQs

```
             <section class="desktop_navigation">
<div class="block explore main with_dropdown">
  <div class="positioner"><img src="images/headers/news.png">
<nav class="dropdown">
<a href="/news/index.html" class="label">News</a>
<a href="/events/index.html" class="label">Events</a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/PBSWestRegion" class="label" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/PBSWestRegion/" class="label" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
<a href="instagram.html" class="label">Instagram</a>    
<a href="restrictedarea/calendar.html" class="label">Calendar</a></nav></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) there's something wrong with the display of the markup in your question 2) where's your CSS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to help you, we a little more than just code. What have you tried? What are you trying to achieve? What isn't working? Please _edit_ your answer to include these elements, so that we have an idea of where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to change instagram.html to 'https://www.instagram.com/PBSWestRegion/' in your href attribute?

Did you also add link your CSS file in the HTML file.
for example :
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" >